# images are not showing in django

Tags: python, django

hi when i am saving images from my admin they are saved in project directory like this images/images/myimg.jpg.. but when i am trying to display them in my template like this

```
    <img src="{{About.image.url}}" alt="profile photo">
```

the image do not displays.. when i inspect the page in chrome... it shows image source unknown..

```
     <img src="(unknown)" alt="profile photo">
```

please see the files ..

settings.py

```
                         STATIC_URL = '/static/'
           STATICFILES_DIRS =[
                     os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'portfolio/static')
                                ]
             STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

             MEDIA_URL  ='/media/'
             MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images')
```

project urls.py

```
         from django.contrib import admin
         from django.urls import path,include
         from django.conf import settings
         from django.conf.urls.static import static
        
           urlpatterns = [

          path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
         path('home/', include("home.urls")),
         path('blog/', include("blog.urls")),


             ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

the model having image is inside a app named 'home'

models.py of home app

```
          from django.db import models
          import datetime
          # Create your models here.
            class About(models.Model):
                 image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
                 desc  = models.TextField()
```

home/views.py

```
            from django.shortcuts import render
             from home.models import *
            from django.views.generic import ListView

           # Create your views here.
           def index(request):
            abt = About.objects.all()
             return render(request,'home/index.html',{'abt': abt.first()})

         def Experience(request):
            Exp = Experience.objects.all()
             return render(request,'home/Experience.html',{'Exp': Exp})


           class MyView(ListView):
            context_object_name = 'name'
              template_name = 'home/index.html'
              queryset = About.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['Experience'] = Experience.objects.all()
    context['Education'] = Education.objects.all()
    context['Award'] = Award.objects.all()
    context['Membership'] = Membership.objects.all()
    context['About'] = self.queryset
    return context
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Which view are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if about you're passing queryset so try looping them and accessing each image

```
{% for data in About %}
 <img src="{{data.image.url}}" alt="profile photo">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi pruthvi .. it worked.. but i have ine question.. this particular model will have only one row ... do we need to use for loop even for singlets

Comment: If you want to send always one object then in queryset instead of `About.objects.all()` pass `About.objects.first()` then no need for for-loop because it will return single object not queryset